# Why the placeholder_text not appearing when state DISABLED even if ENABLED using if not appearing

Tags: python, customtkinter

so this is the code i was trying to get the result in this i have other question can u guys help me in getting details of an exe file like title, company trademark etc(its secondary tho), main problem is as i mentioned in title the state=DISABLED placeholder text is empty even after making it NORMAL later

```
def assembly_page():
    def choose_clone_file():
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Clone File", filetypes=[("Assembly Files", "*.exe")])
        details = pefile.PE(file)
        fileinfo = details.FileInfo[0]
        for info in details.FileInfo:
            if hasattr(info, 'StringTable'):
                fileinfo = info
                break

        name = fileinfo.StringTable.entries.get('FileDescription', '') 

        title.configure(text=name)


    def randomize_assembly():
        ...

    def check():
        if check_var.get() == 'on':
            check_box.configure(text='Enabled')
            title.configure(state=NORMAL)
            product.configure(state=NORMAL)
            description.configure(state=NORMAL)
            copyright.configure(state=NORMAL)
            company.configure(state=NORMAL)
            trademark.configure(state=NORMAL)
            version.configure(state=NORMAL)
            clone_file.configure(state=NORMAL)
            randomize.configure(state=NORMAL)
        else:
            check_box.configure(text='Disabled')
            title.configure(state=DISABLED)
            product.configure(state=DISABLED)
            description.configure(state=DISABLED)
            copyright.configure(state=DISABLED)
            company.configure(state=DISABLED)
            trademark.configure(state=DISABLED)
            version.configure(state=DISABLED)
            clone_file.configure(state=DISABLED)
            randomize.configure(state=DISABLED)

        
    
    assembly_page_frame = CTkFrame(main_frame)

    title_var = StringVar()

    product_var = StringVar()

    description_var = StringVar()

    copyright_var = StringVar()

    company_var = StringVar()

    trademark_var = StringVar()

    version_var = StringVar()

    check_var = StringVar(value='off')

    check_box = CTkCheckBox(assembly_page_frame,text="Disabled",variable=check_var,onvalue='on',offvalue='off',command=check)
    check_box.place(x=10,y=10)

    title = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Title...',state=DISABLED,width=250,textvariable=title_var)
    title.place(x=50,y=50)
    
    product = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Product',state=DISABLED,width=250,textvariable=product_var)
    product.place(x=350,y=50)

    description = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='description',state=DISABLED,width=250,textvariable=description_var)
    description.place(x=50,y=100)

    copyright = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Copyright',state=DISABLED,width=250,textvariable=copyright_var)
    copyright.place(x=350,y=100)

    company = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Company',state=DISABLED,width=250,textvariable=company_var)
    company.place(x=50,y=150)

    trademark = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='TreadeMark',state=DISABLED,width=250,textvariable=trademark_var)
    trademark.place(x=350,y=150)

    version = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='0.0.0.0',textvariable=version_var,width=180)
    version.place(x=50,y=200)

    clone_file = CTkButton(assembly_page_frame,text='Clone File',state=DISABLED,command=choose_clone_file)
    clone_file.place(x=250,y=200)

    randomize = CTkButton(assembly_page_frame,text='Randomize',state=DISABLED)
    randomize.place(x=400,y=200)

    assembly_page_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

and this is the main code

```
set_appearance_mode("System")
app = CTk()

app.geometry("625x625")
app.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
app.title("FG_Crypter")

options_frame = CTkFrame(app)

input_file_var = StringVar()
output_file_var = StringVar()

icon_file_var = StringVar()

basic_btn = CTkButton(options_frame,text="Basic",font=("Arial",13), width=125,command=lambda: switch(basic_indicate,basic_page))
basic_btn.place(x=0,y=0)

basic_indicate = CTkLabel(options_frame,text="",bg_color='blue',width=100,height=2)
basic_indicate.place(x=12,y=30)

icon_btn = CTkButton(options_frame,text="Icon",font=("Arial",13), width=125,command=lambda: switch(icon_indicate,icon_page))
icon_btn.place(x=125,y=0)

icon_indicate = CTkLabel(options_frame,text="", width=100,height=2)
icon_indicate.place(x=137,y=30)

Assembly_btn = CTkButton(options_frame,text="Assembly",font=("Arial",13), width=125,command=lambda: switch(assembly_indicate,assembly_page))
Assembly_btn.place(x=250,y=0)

assembly_indicate = CTkLabel(options_frame,text="",width=100,height=2)
assembly_indicate.place(x=262,y=30)

Advanced_btn = CTkButton(options_frame,text="Advanced",font=("Arial",13), width=125,command=lambda: switch(advanced_indicate))
Advanced_btn.place(x=375,y=0)

advanced_indicate = CTkLabel(options_frame,text="",width=100,height=2)
advanced_indicate.place(x=387,y=30)

Build_btn = CTkButton(options_frame,text="Build",font=("Arial",13), width=125,command=lambda: switch(build_indicate))
Build_btn.place(x=500,y=0)

build_indicate = CTkLabel(options_frame,text="",width=100,height=2)
build_indicate.place(x=512,y=30)
options_frame.pack(pady=5)
options_frame.propagate(False)
options_frame.configure(width=650,height=35)
main_frame = CTkFrame(app)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
basic_page()
app.mainloop()
```

basically all code is custom tkinter python this is a oss project on github u can visit it if u want

Answer (score 0):

### Description:

The issue is very simple if you look up the documentation and observe the state function syntax it only accepts strings for example: "normal" and "disabled".

### Solution:

So the solution to your code is to change the state not by using `state = Normal` but instead use `state = "normal"`

```py
def assembly_page():
    def choose_clone_file():
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Clone File", filetypes=[("Assembly Files", "*.exe")])
        details = pefile.PE(file)
        fileinfo = details.FileInfo[0]
        for info in details.FileInfo:
            if hasattr(info, 'StringTable'):
                fileinfo = info
                break

        name = fileinfo.StringTable.entries.get('FileDescription', '') 

        title.configure(text=name)


    def randomize_assembly():
        ...

    def check():
        if check_var.get() == 'on':
            check_box.configure(text='Enabled')
            title.configure(state="normal")
            product.configure(state="normal")
            description.configure(state="normal")
            copyright.configure(state="normal")
            company.configure(state="normal")
            trademark.configure(state="normal")
            version.configure(state="normal")
            clone_file.configure(state="normal")
            randomize.configure(state="normal")
        else:
            check_box.configure(text='Disabled')
            title.configure(state="disabled")
            product.configure(state="disabled")
            description.configure(state="disabled")
            copyright.configure(state="disabled")
            company.configure(state="disabled")
            trademark.configure(state="disabled")
            version.configure(state="disabled")
            clone_file.configure(state="disabled")
            randomize.configure(state="disabled")

        
    
    assembly_page_frame = CTkFrame(main_frame)

    title_var = StringVar()

    product_var = StringVar()

    description_var = StringVar()

    copyright_var = StringVar()

    company_var = StringVar()

    trademark_var = StringVar()

    version_var = StringVar()

    check_var = StringVar(value='off')

    check_box = CTkCheckBox(assembly_page_frame,text="Disabled",variable=check_var,onvalue='on',offvalue='off',command=check)
    check_box.place(x=10,y=10)

    title = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Title...',state="disabled",width=250,textvariable=title_var)
    title.place(x=50,y=50)
    
    product = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Product',state="disabled",width=250,textvariable=product_var)
    product.place(x=350,y=50)

    description = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='description',state="disabled",width=250,textvariable=description_var)
    description.place(x=50,y=100)

    copyright = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Copyright',state="disabled",width=250,textvariable=copyright_var)
    copyright.place(x=350,y=100)

    company = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='Company',state="disabled",width=250,textvariable=company_var)
    company.place(x=50,y=150)

    trademark = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='TreadeMark',state="disabled",width=250,textvariable=trademark_var)
    trademark.place(x=350,y=150)

    version = CTkEntry(assembly_page_frame,placeholder_text='0.0.0.0',textvariable=version_var,width=180)
    version.place(x=50,y=200)

    clone_file = CTkButton(assembly_page_frame,text='Clone File',state="disabled",command=choose_clone_file)
    clone_file.place(x=250,y=200)

    randomize = CTkButton(assembly_page_frame,text='Randomize',state="disabled")
    randomize.place(x=400,y=200)

    assembly_page_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

Comment: but this is not the answer the problem is placeholdertext not coming up i use from ctk import * so i can use whatever i want like END DISABLED NORMAL etc

Comment: You have marked every entry's state to be disabled so how can you enter your data in there. If I can get the complete source code or a GitHub link I can guide you in depth as the code is just snippets of the whole code.